# Fazer merge em duas planilhas formato .csv no R

Tags: r, data.frame, dplyr, merge, tidyverse

Estou fazendo um trabalho utilizando o portal da transparência, preciso juntar dois bancos de dados **prof1.csv** e **prof2.csv**. O resultado final do *merge*, que denominei **prof.csv**, está duplicando linhas devido as colunas 18 de salario bruto e 19 de salario liquido. Gostaria do resultado igual a [Prof.csv](https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/salarioDocente/master/Prof.csv). Ou seja, não desejo duplicar linhas mesmo se os salários são distintos e quero manter os valores de salários de meses distintos na mesma linha. Segue uma pequena parte do código que estou utilizando.

```
url1 <- url("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/salarioDocente/master/prof1.csv")
url2 <- url("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/salarioDocente/master/prof2.csv")
prof1 <- read.csv2(url1, header = TRUE,encoding = "ASCII")
prof2 <- read.csv2(url2, header = TRUE,encoding = "ASCII")
Prof <- merge(prof1,prof2,by=c("ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL"       ,"NOME"                     ,"CPF"                     ,
                             "DATA_INICIO_AFASTAMENTO"  ,"DATA_TERMINO_AFASTAMENTO",
                             "JORNADA_DE_TRABALHO"      ,"DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO"      ,"UF_EXERCICIO"            ,
                             "Nivel"                    ,"LOTACAO"                  ,"REG_JURIDICO"             ,"VINCULO"                 ,
                             "CARGO"                    ,"Org_Exercicio"            ,"Tempo")
                ,all.x= T, all.y= T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `merge` está duplicando as linhas pelo fato de que existem cargos e níveis diferentes entre as 2 bases de dados para a mesma pessoa.

Por exemplo, em `prof1`, `Fulano de Tal 1` possui `CARGO` `P3G` e em `prof2` seu cargo é `MS`.

Dito isso, você deve retirar essas duas variáveis do argumento `by`.

```
merge(prof1, prof2, by = c("ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL", "NOME", "CPF", "DATA_INICIO_AFASTAMENTO",
                           "DATA_TERMINO_AFASTAMENTO", "JORNADA_DE_TRABALHO", "DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO",
                           "UF_EXERCICIO", "LOTACAO", "REG_JURIDICO", "VINCULO", "Org_Exercicio", "Tempo"),
  all = T)  %>% 
  select(-contains(".x")) %>% 
  rename(Nivel = Nivel.y, CARGO = CARGO.y)
```

Incluí os comando `select` e `rename` para manter apenas as variáveis `Nivel` e `CARGO` do base `prof2`

Comment: Oi Rafael, não tinha percebido isso. Tem como manter as colunas `Nível` e `CARGO` com os valores da planilha **prof2.csv** usando a função `merge`? Nesse caso, `Nível.y` e `CARGO.y` são as respostas que me interessam!

Comment: As variáveis com final `.x` são de `prof1` e as com final `.y` são a de `prof2`.

Comment: Sim, entendo isso, mas as planilhas com que trabalho são enormes, por isso, desejo saber a forma mais simples de manter sempre os valores de prof2. Com novos códigos consigo faser isso, por exemplo:       
Prof$Nivel <- Prof$Nivel.y
Prof$Cargo <- Prof$CARGO.y
Prof <- Prof %>% select(1:13,16:21,24:25), mas se fosse possível manter já no primeiro código essa informação seria melhor!

Comment: Adicionei duas linhas de código, veja se atende o que você deseja